# Apache 2.4 - process hanging intermittently

Tags: apache-2.4

I am facing some issues with httpd process getting hung intermittently. While troubleshooting I could see that some of the semaphore counts is greater than zero. I could make it work by clearing those semID's. But wanted to understand what's causing it.

Below is some of the information.

Version:
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

OS - Centos 7

```
ipcs -s -i 45187195
Semaphore Array semid=45187195
uid=48 gid=48 cuid=0 cgid=0
mode=0600, access_perms=0600
nsems = 1
otime = Tue Feb 23 12:14:35 2021
ctime = Mon Feb 8 09:45:38 2021
semnum value ncount zcount pid
0 0 1 0 19944
 
ps -ef | grep 19944
root 2409 19130 0 17:06 pts/0 00:00:00 grep --color=auto 19944
apache 19944 24691 0 12:14 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
 
ipcs -us
------ Semaphore Status --------
used arrays = 128
allocated semaphores = 128
 
ipcs -ls
------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = 256
max semaphores per array = 250
max semaphores system wide = 64000
max ops per semop call = 32
semaphore max value = 32767
 
ps -efL|grep httpd | awk '{print $2}' | uniq -c
60 2471
1 2509
80 12617
202 19944
1 20149
76 21108
1 24691
1 24692
75 28558
76 32344

wget localhost
--2021-02-23 17:10:24-- http://localhost/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80...

tcp6 512 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN 19944/httpd
 
nc -zv localhost 80
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 127.0.0.1:80.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 1.01 seconds

**Modules loaded:**
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 allowmethods_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_dbd_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_socache_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_dbd_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 cache_disk_module (shared)
 data_module (shared)
 dbd_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 dumpio_module (shared)
 echo_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 remoteip_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_plain_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_dbm_module (shared)
 socache_memcache_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 lua_module (shared)
 mpm_worker_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_heartbeat_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 systemd_module (shared)
 cgid_module (shared)
 wsgi_module (shared)
```

1.During this time the number of connection spikes up before process get hang.
2. No errors or anything in logs. It just hangs and stop accepting traffic. No maxclient error in logs.
3. I did try gdb and strace but nothing helpful in there.

Appreciate any pointers on why this is causing. Please let me know if any additional questions,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it actually helps but I had a similar issue when Apache was running out of semaphores. In order to fix it I had to do this:

```
for i in `ipcs -s | awk '/nobody/ {print $2}'`; do { ipcrm -s $i ; } done;
echo "kernel.msgmni = 1024" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "kernel.sem = 250 256000 32 1024" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
systemctl restart httpd
```

In your case **max numer of arrays** is **256**. Increase that to 1024 by running the commands above!

You can actually see the current semaphores configuration by running:

```
ipcs -l
```

Note: if your Apache web server runs using a different user than nobody then just replace **nobody** with **apache** or **www-data** or whatever user you're using.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Yes, clearing the semaphores helps (as i mentioned in the post). Wanted to understand why its causing the process to hang. 

Also from the output I posted, if I understand correctly, its not exceeding the semaphore limit. Pls let me know if am wrong there.

Apache is running as "apache user".

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell why it hangs. You should check the apache logs and see if there are any issues there. Also check the server logs (maybe you are running out of free memory at some times). And yes, the settings I've recommend are pretty much for the scenario when you run out of free semaphores. That being said, increasing the default values won't do any harm.

Comment: Hi - I tried your suggestion but still facing the issue. I tried to put the semaphore info in a comment but it's exceeding, so posted it as an answer. Not sure if any other good way to do it. I don't see anything in the error logs. 

Any other pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did try to update the configuration. Even after the problem exists.

```
ipcs -l

------ Messages Limits --------
max queues system wide = 1024
max size of message (bytes) = 65536
default max size of queue (bytes) = 65536

------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 67108864
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 17179869184
min seg size (bytes) = 1

------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = 1024
max semaphores per array = 250
max semaphores system wide = 256000
max ops per semop call = 32
semaphore max value = 32767
```

I don't see anything in the logs.

```
**ipcs -s -i 111968451**

Semaphore Array semid=111968451
uid=48   gid=48  cuid=0  cgid=0
mode=0600, access_perms=0600
nsems = 1
otime = Fri Mar  5 16:13:49 2021
ctime = Fri Mar  5 07:53:50 2021
semnum     value      ncount     zcount     pid
0          0          1          0          3305

**ps -ef | grep 3305**

root      1598 28631  0 18:18 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 3305
apache    3305  1362  0 16:13 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

]#**netstat -tnlp | grep 80**
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8089            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3391/splunkd
tcp6     512      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1362/httpd
```

Any other pointers to troubleshoot this would be really appreciated. Thank you